# How can I fix Error message with Cypress "TypeError:cyBySel is not function"

Tags: cypress

```js
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

describe('Home Page', () => {
  it('Access to the home page ', () => {
    cy.visit('https://qa-dash.azurewebsites.net/')
    cy.url().should('eq', 'https://qa-dash.azurewebsites.net/login')
    cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .MuiToolbar-root > .MuiTypography-root').should(
      'be.visible'
    )
  })

  it('All the buttons should display properly', () => {
    cy.visit('https://qa-dash.azurewebsites.net/')
    cy.getBySel('aboutusButton').click()
    cy.go('back')
    cy.getBySel('termssButton').click()
    cy.url().should('include', '/terms')
    cy.go('back')
    cy.getBySel('privacysButton').click()
    cy.contains('Terms of Service').click
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are are getting error on this line `cy.getBySel('aboutusButton').click()`. This is not a valid cypress command. I am not sure if you are using any custom commands or not, Please check that. If you are just trying to click the `About Us` button you can use:

```js
cy.contains('MuiButton-label', 'About us').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If getBySel is a custom command, then check if that function has been properly imported in the index.js file.